# Duplicate classes in different Java libraries leads to compilation errors

Tags: java, selenium, generics, compiler-errors, appium

I am having trouble with the Appium java client because it seems they did weird things with their project.

Basically, they are using Selenium in their project which should work just fine but they copied one package from Selenium partly to their project (**org.openqa.selenium**) and made some small adaptions to the classes inside. Basically, they added generics to the interfaces. Now we have duplicate classes in the same package in different libraries which of course leads to problems.

I created a simple Gradle project to demonstrate that.
Following my **build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    api 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

And my class **Interactions.java**:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Interactions {

    public static void touchWebElement(By by, WebDriver driver) {
        touchWebElement(driver.findElement(by), driver);
    }

    public static void touchWebElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Now if I compile that project I get the following error:

```
The method touchWebElement(By, WebDriver) is ambiguous for the type Interactions    Interactions.java   line 8
```

I think it is ambiguous because the interface **WebElement** exists twice.

How can I fix that problem?

- Using appium-client <= 4.0.0 would work, but I need a newer version.
- Currently, I just deleted the duplicate package from the jar and included this jar into my project. I really just deleted it with 7zip. This clears that compilation error but I will probably soon face other problems because the appium jar is not complete and the appium project would not even compile without that package.
- The Selenium guys probably won't change anything (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/863).
- The Appium guys probably don't know how to fix that, so am I: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1021

**Solution:**

With help of the accepted answer I was able to fix those issues.
Although I needed to come up with a slightly different solution.
The problem I faced was that classes which called my Interactions.java needed those casts too which would lead in 1000+ adaptions. To prevent this I changed my methods to take Object as parameter:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Interactions {
    public static void touchWebElement(Object object, WebDriver driver){
        WebElement webElement = castObjectToWebElement(element, driver);
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

    private static WebElement castObjectToWebElement(Object object, WebDriver driver) {
        if (object instanceof WebElement) {
            return (WebElement) object;
        } else if (object instanceof By) {
            return driver.findElement((By) object);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type");
    }
}
```

It might not be an optimal solution but it works and won't need changes in all our other classes and everyone can work with those Interaction methods as until now.

Comment: It is bad business to have this kind of duplications. Perhaps someone here can come out with some sort of patch to get it to work but it will bite you back eventually. It makes more sense for the appium (client) code to be the one to change... if they really need those changes then they should create their API classes with a separate package and or name delegating on selenium classes for their work.

Comment: I see that SeleniumHQ has a github repo. You make consider to fork their code and add the client's modifications there. You might be able to publish on some (private) maven repo that dependency and pull it instead of the official Selenium artifact however that is not that important since you could simply add their jar build to your own build process and aggregate the dependency the old way. Hopefully this does not break any license restrictions.

Comment: What happens if you rename one of the methods to not be the same name as the other method?  Reading up on this error message, it seems that the problem may not be about how Appium worked with Selenium.

Comment: @ValentinRuano Thank you for your reply. I don't think that will be much better than my current workaround. I probably won't be able to stay up to date with both libraries if I am able to fix it. There were many changes since version 4.0.0.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock Thank you for your reply. This works at least in the small example project above. But I am not sure if I can do that in my real project. It is basically a library which is used from more than 50 people. These methods exist since 5 years, so I am not sure if everyone is happy with renaming them. But I will give it a try.

Comment: Renaming methods solves the problem mentioned above. It would lead to adaption of ~6000 method calls. 
But it does not work anyway, because I get another error. 
Following import is not recognized:
`import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are not duplicate classes but the way generics are used. Here is a little [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) replicating the situation in Appium's `WebDriver` class:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public interface WebElement {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public interface WebDriver {
  <T extends WebElement> T findElement();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class Application {
  static WebDriver webDriver;

  static void myOverloadedMethod(String text) {}
  static void myOverloadedMethod(WebElement text) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // These 3 variants work
    myOverloadedMethod("test");
    myOverloadedMethod((WebElement) webDriver.findElement());
    WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement();
    myOverloadedMethod(webElement);

    // This one does not work
    myOverloadedMethod(webDriver.findElement());
  }
}
```

**Explanation:** Due to [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)  `doSomething`'s generic return type `<T extends WebElement>` evaluates to `Object`, so when trying to use that result for calling `myOverloadedMethod(..)` the compiler does not know which method to select.

**Solution:** You need to help by casting or explicitly declaring a type for a variable containing the method parameter.

**P.S.:** If you would modify the interface definition from `interface WebDriver` to `interface WebDriver<T>`, the compilation error would go away. But Appium's implementation does not do that, maybe because they want to stay as compatible(?) as possible to the original Selenium class. You have to ask them.

---

**Update:** Because the OP seems to have problems understanding my answer or to believe I did not try his sample code, which of course I used to reproduce and understand his problem:

```java
package de.scrum_master.appium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Interactions {
  public static void touchWebElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {}

  public static void touchWebElement(By by, WebDriver driver) {
    // Works
    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(by);
    touchWebElement(webElement, driver);
    // Works
    touchWebElement((WebElement) driver.findElement(by), driver);
    // Ambiguous due to type erasure -> does not work
    touchWebElement(driver.findElement(by), driver);
  }
}
```

There is absolutely no need rename methods, re-package any classes or perform other types of Maven/Gradle stunts here.

Comment: Why didn't you try my example? Can you show me what you exactly mean with casting a type for the method parameter? Preffered on the example from the question.
Correct, they want to stay compatible and Selenium won't change anything in that area.

Comment: Of course I did. I can reproduce the problem with Gradle or Maven, JCenter or Maven Central repositories. But I did more: I analysed the Appium + Selenium classes and interfaces for you in order to understand the problem and show you with a minimal code sample what you can do. What is unclear about that Just change your code in the first method to `touchWebElement((WebElement) driver.findElement(by), driver);` according to my example or assign the parameter to a typed `WebElement` variable before using it in the method call. Super easy. Please read my answer more carefully. Thank you.

Comment: You are right I should have read your answer more carefully. Thank you for updating your answer, it is much clearer now. My IDE automatically removed those casts so I did not think that this would solve my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, actually my IDE IntelliJ IDEA even suggests the cast.

Comment: I am using eclipse and have save actions enabled which remove unnecessary casts. Unfortunately in this case the cast isn't unnecessary.

Comment: Yep, exactly. IDEA seems to be a bit more intelligent than Eclipse in this regard.